# Difference between client-id and id of client in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Well, the title speaks for itself. In many places from Keycloak docs I encountered this statement

> id of client (not client-id)

For now this statement sounds so stupid to me as I do not understand the difference between client-id and id of the client. Can somebody explain me this, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're creating a new client, you specify its Client ID (or simply client's name), e.g. "my-super-client". This is supposed to be unique across the realm and usually used in OAuth calls, e.g. as a `client_id` in "Client Credentials" flow (in pair with `client_secret`).

However, when creating a new client, KeyCloak issues an internal unique ID like this `3f7dd007-568f-4f4a-bbac-2e6bfff93860`. You may find it in a URL when opening a page of your "my-super-client" in the web interface. This one is supposed to be a unique ID of any resource that KeyCloak creates during its lifespan.

Keeping this in mind, I think it'd be clear from the context of documentation which one is "id of client" and which one is "client-id" as you stated in the question. If not, please give a link here.

Answer (score 1):

#### ID of a client `id`

In [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) every resource gets a unique `id`, which is a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), including clients. The purpose of the ID is to allow for precise and unambiguous identification of the client within [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org). This is necessary because human-readable identifiers like `client-id` can be changed, but the internal `id` cannot. The unchangeable, unique `id` ensures integrity and consistency of references to the client within [Keycloak's](https://www.keycloak.org) internal system and database.

#### Client-ID of a client `client-id`

The `client-id` (which is human-readable) is crucial for [OAuth2/OpenID](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/whats-the-difference-between-oauth-openid-connect-and-saml) Connect interactions. This identifier is sent as the `client-id` parameter in requests to the authorization server ([Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) in this case). It's used for client identification, and the server uses it to look up the client's settings and other data. The `client-id` is exposed to users and systems outside of [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org), unlike the internal ID.

Contextual Interpretation: In the documentation and in common use, `client-id` typically refers to the human-readable identifier, while `id` or *"ID of a client"* refers to the internal, non-human-friendly [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). However, as [**@vladimir-salin**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839518/vladimir-salin) mentioned, it's always best to refer to the specific context to ensure correct interpretation. For instance, when using [Keycloak's](https://www.keycloak.org) REST API, you'll mostly be using the internal `id`.

#### Definition of a "client"

*"Clients are entities that can request Keycloak to authenticate a user. Most often, clients are applications and services that want to use Keycloak to secure themselves and provide a single sign-on solution. Clients can also be entities that just want to request identity information or an access token so that they can securely invoke other services on the network that are secured by Keycloak."*
~ Quote sourced from [www.keycloak.org](https://www.keycloak.org)

#### Conclusion

While both `id` and `client-id` serve as identifiers for a client in [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org), they serve different purposes and are used in different contexts - the `id` for internal use by Keycloak and its APIs, and the `client-id` for external use in [OAuth2/OpenID](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/whats-the-difference-between-oauth-openid-connect-and-saml) Connect interactions.

Comment: TLDR: `client-id` typically refers to the human-readable identifier, while `id` or _"ID of a client"_ refers to the internal, non-human-friendly UUID.
This is a direct quote from Kevin O.'s answer. Just this line itself would have been helpful in answer to this question.